# PHP - Echo input values in foreach loop

Tags: php

In my form, I generate input fields with php in my add.php page:

```
<?php 
$inc = 0;

$inputNames = array( 
    array("Name", 'r_name', 'rd-id-'),
    array("Surname", 'r_surname', 'rd-id-'),
    array("Phone", 'r_phone', 'rd-id-'),
    array("Email", 'r_email', 'rd-id-'),
);

foreach ($inputNames as $inp) { ?>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label><?php echo $inp[0]; ?></label>
            <input id="<?php echo $inp[2] . $inc; ?>" type="text" 
            class="form-control border-input" 
            placeholder="<?php echo $inp[0]; ?>" 
            name="<?php echo $inp[1]; ?>" 
            value="">
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php 
    $inc++;
}
?>
```

The question is, how can I echo values from database in this loop?
For example, in my edit.php page, I have variables like this:

```
    $name = $_POST['r_name'];
    $surname = $_POST['r_surname'];
    $phone = $_POST['r_phone'];
    $email= $_POST['r_email'];
```

I have tried to modifie the $inputNames array, to add a third value like:
    `<?php echo inp[3]; ?>`
but it didn't work.

Comment: _how can I echo values from database_ I don't see any connection to db nor queries that show your attempt

Comment: It is connected to db. I can echo values  for each input fields like this value="<?php echo $name; ?>" etc, but how can I echo them in this foreach loop

Comment: _how can I echo them in this foreach loop..._ Try something and come back(with relevant code) when you are stuck

Comment: Can you show what you tried and describe what happened?

Answer (score 0):

```
Use while loop instead of foreach 

    while($inp = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    { 
        echo '<div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>'.$inp["colname1"].'</label>
                    <input id="'.$inp["colname2"].$inc.'" type="text" class="form control border-input" placeholder="'.$inp["colname3"].'" name="'.$inp["colname3"].'" value="">
                </div>
        </div>';
}
```